# Cannot access virtual machine via ping from the physical host machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, freebsd

I'm installing a FreeBSD Server on VirtualBox. I set up the IP address (`192.168.10.5`) for the virtual server to run a mail server and the host computer(Windows 7) with `192.168.10.184`. The two machines cannot communicate or connect to each other.

I cannot ping from the virtual machine to the host and vice versa. The host machine connects to a LAN. I want the mail server to run frm a VMachine.

I think it's a problem with the network configuration of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

In the settings for this VM, what kind of attachment is configured for your network adapter  (Settings -> Network -> Adapter 1 tab)?

If you're set to the default (NAT), then you probably want to switch to use **bridged networking**.  You'll be asked to associate a physical network interface.  Pick the one that is on your `192.168.10` network.

If none if this is news to you, or if that doesn't work, I can try to assist further.

For more background, see [the networking section of the VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

Answer (score 0):

I tried something which worked well (on windows server 2012):
You just go to computer, then right click on network connection, properties, "change advanced network settings"
And then you allow file and printer sharing.

I know it sounds strange but it worked fine for me

Answer (score -2):

Before installing with the OS we need to check the connectivity be both physical & Virtual machines.

check with the duplex settings on both with Physical machines & Virtual machine.